# Selenium: css query regarding get_attribute() function

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to find the attribute value of the title attribute.

Now, I have a list of similar links on the same page and I want to select the first link and get its title attribute.

I have used the following selenium command:

```
self.se.get_attribute("css=a[href*='radio?rid=']:nth-of-type(1)@title")
```

But it is giving me an error.

Could someone please help me figure out the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use XPath syntax instead of CSS selectors. You didn't post any HTML to match, so therefore a made up example: to get the title of the first link found in a div with id `myDiv`, use the following:

```
self.se.get_attribute("xpath=//div[@id='myDiv']//a[1]@title")
```

Where:

- `//div[@id='myDiv']` matches any div with id "myDiv";
- `//a[1]` select the first link found anywhere in the previously selected div (use `2` for the second, and so on.
- `@title` specifies the attribute you want to retrieve.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am looking for something specifically using CSS

Comment: Please post the segment of HTML you are trying to match, along with the error you are getting. The selector looks fine, so we need the context it is failing in to determine the cause. Also, are you dynamically updating the page (e.g. using Ajax)? In that case, are you sure the element is present at the time you are querying for it?

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. You are right, the selector is actually fine, the problem was that it failed sometimes when  the HTML tag did not contain title attribute. But when the title attribute was there everything was fine.

Comment: I have one other query, could you help me with that also...thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804722/selenium-how-to-check-if-a-particular-text-is-present-in-a-particular-attribute