# SELENIUM: how to check if a particular text is present in a particular attribute of HTML tag

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a HTML tags:

```
<a href="rid=7059"> abc </a>
<a href="pid=8059"> fgh </a>
<a href="cid=9059"> cxq </a>
```

HOw do I check if a particular tag exists with the `href` attribute containing `rid` (First tag in the above example)

`get_attribute()` gets the value of a specified attribute but how do i check when in a page any such tag exists whose attribute value is `rid` ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the language you are using, so from personal preference I'm assuming Python. Other languages shouldn't really differ, though.

The `is_element_present` function can be used for this. From the Selenium source:

```
def is_element_present(self,locator):
    """
    Verifies that the specified element is somewhere on the page.

    'locator' is an element locator
    """
    return self.get_boolean("isElementPresent", [locator,]
```

For the locator you could use something along the lines of `"css=a[href*='rid']"`.

Comment: Yes, i am using python. BUt this is going to check for only one particular tag which is mentioned in the locator. The scenario is that I have a whole lot of tags which have 'href' attribute in them but I need to check if there is a tag which contains 'rid' in its href attribute.\

Answer (score 2):

When locating the element, use XPath expression like `//a[contains(@href,'rid')]`, so `isElementPresent(//a[contains(@href,'rid')])` should do.

Comment: thanks. could you please help me with CSS  instead of XPATH, as i am using CSS. So, basically what would the locator syntax (CSS) be for is_element_present() func

Comment: css=a[href^='rid'] would match all links which href attribute starts with rid. More info: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/